# Customize gridview repositoryItemComboBox

Tags: c#, devexpress, overriding

I am using a Devexpress 14.2 gridview. I am coding with C# form. I need to customize my repositoryItemComboBox. I have a class  that has 
string name
string value
string group
bool combox
list list.

so some cells in a column will have different list or items.
example
list 1 :
com 1
com 2
com 3 
list 2
yes 
no
list 3
1
2
3
they are all in the same column called Value.
I only have 3 columns : Name Value and Group

so how do I override the repositoryItemComboBox1 object?

Comment: Are you saying that you need to place a RepositoryItemComboBox into a grid's cells, but use a different data source for some cells?

Comment: yes that is what i am saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the GridView's [CustomRowCellEdit event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) to dynamically assign an editor to a single cell at runtime.

See also:  [Assigning Editors to Individual Cells](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument747.aspx)